# Detach all other terminals except current one from a tmux session

Tags: login, tmux, gnu-screen, session

Is there a way to detach all  terminals from a running `tmux` session, except the one i'm actually using?

It seems a little weird, but the meaning of doing this is to keep some "persistency" layer to end user remote session, while ensuring that the user is using the system on only "one shell".

As explained [here](https://ryanmo.co/2015/05/09/automatically-attach-tmux-in-ssh-session/), it's easy to create sessions based on user names:

```
if [[ "$TMUX" == "" ]] &&
        [[ "$SSH_CONNECTION" != "" ]]; then
    # Attempt to discover a detached session and attach
    # it, else create a new session
    WHOAMI=$(whoami)
    if tmux has-session -t $WHOAMI 2>/dev/null; then
    tmux -2 attach-session -t $WHOAMI
    else
        tmux -2 new-session -s $WHOAMI
    fi
fi
```

But i want also, to make sure that the last attached terminal is the only one that remains attached to the user's `tmux` session.

Does it have a way to accomplished that? I also accept solutions based on `screen` (or other multiplexers) ;)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If I've understood your question correctly, the `-d` option to `attach-session` does what you want:

```
tmux -2 attach-session -d -t $WHOAMI
```

This attaches to the named target session and detaches all other clients.

You can do something similar after the session is attached, with `detach-client`'s `-a` and `-t` options: name the client with `-t`, and add `-a` to detach all clients apart from the named client.

`screen` also has a `-d` option which does the same thing.

Comment: How could i have missed that after reading the man pages? You are right, but i cant leave any traces of logged session. After detaching the other terminals, how can i force a "logout" to avoid a shell opened at a prompt?

Comment: Assuming the attached sessions were attached from the `.bashrc` containing the snippet in your question, detaching them will continue executing `.bashrc` after the `tmux -2 attach-session` and `tmux -2 new-session` lines; so you can add an `exit` there which will exit the shell after `tmux` detaches. Alternatively, setting `TMOUT` to a positive integer will close idle shells when they time out.